# VB.net deserialize XML into Class while ignoring some tags

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to deserialize some XML returned from a web service. I have created a model class to convert the XML to, however I have no idea what all the possible tags are that might be included in the XML, and when I come across one I don't have a property for I get an exception. Is there a way to deserialize the XML into an object where it just ignores any XML tags that I don't have a property for?

For example, let's say I have this class

```
Public Class Person

    Property FirstName as String
    Property LastName as String
    Property Address as String

End Class
```

And XML like this,

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Address>1234 Sesame Street</Address>
</Person>
```

Now, I don't have a property for Age, but I would still like to deserialize this into a model object with the other three properties being populated instead of throwing an error. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you say you deserialize the XML into VB object, how do you do this exactly?

Comment: `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` doesn't care whether a property is missing in the specified Class object Type. `Age` is simply ignored.